# I can no longer access Lang within a Controller after upgrading to Play 2.3.0 for Scala

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.3

Before I upgraded Play to the release 2.3.0, I could access the Lang object from a Controller's Action like this:

```
def myAction = { request =>
        println(lang(request))
}
```

and the Lang object were displayed on the screen. Now I get a compilation error. How can I access the Lang object after upgrading?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the [Play 2.3 API docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.mvc.Controller), it appears that `lang` was renamed to `request2lang`.

There are at least a couple other functions in the `Controller` trait that have been renamed as well.

`flash` -> `request2flash`

`session` -> `request2session`

Comment: Those methods are `implicit`, So we can use request object like `flash` or `session`